# Can I simplify this VB.net code so I don't have to repeat so much?

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a scheduling algorithm.  My code is getting very long. Can anyone suggest how can I make my code shorter as I have to repeat the same thing many times below and where the outer else is 4 or 5 I have to repeat it even more:

Here's an example of just part of my code:

```
 ElseIf Val(jobs_txt.Text) = 3 Then
            If (a < b And b < c) Then
                awt1_lbl.Text = Val(0)
                awt2_lbl.Text = a
                awt3_lbl.Text = a + b
                y = (Val(awt1_lbl.Text) + Val(awt2_lbl.Text) + Val(awt3_lbl.Text)) / 3
                awt_ans.Text = y
            ElseIf (a < c And c < b) Then
                awt1_lbl.Text = Val(0)
                awt2_lbl.Text = a + b
                awt3_lbl.Text = a
                y = (Val(awt1_lbl.Text) + Val(awt2_lbl.Text) + Val(awt3_lbl.Text)) / 3
                awt_ans.Text = y
            ElseIf (b < a And a < c) Then
                awt1_lbl.Text = a
                awt2_lbl.Text = Val(0)
                awt3_lbl.Text = a + b
                y = (Val(awt1_lbl.Text) + Val(awt2_lbl.Text) + Val(awt3_lbl.Text)) / 3
                awt_ans.Text = y
            ElseIf (b < c And c < a) Then
                awt1_lbl.Text = a + b
                awt2_lbl.Text = Val(0)
                awt3_lbl.Text = a
                y = (Val(awt1_lbl.Text) + Val(awt2_lbl.Text) + Val(awt3_lbl.Text)) / 3
                awt_ans.Text = y
            ElseIf (c < a And a < b) Then
                awt1_lbl.Text = a
                awt2_lbl.Text = a + b
                awt3_lbl.Text = Val(0)
                y = (Val(awt1_lbl.Text) + Val(awt2_lbl.Text) + Val(awt3_lbl.Text)) / 3
                awt_ans.Text = y
            ElseIf (c < b And b < a) Then
                awt1_lbl.Text = a + b
                awt2_lbl.Text = a
                awt3_lbl.Text = Val(0)
                y = (Val(awt1_lbl.Text) + Val(awt2_lbl.Text) + Val(awt3_lbl.Text)) / 3
                awt_ans.Text = y
            End If
```

Comment: Start by explaining what your code is doing, then we might be able to help...

Comment: I have a textbox that a user can enter how many jobs the program will process. The textbox will only allow values from 2 to 5. When the user click enter, the number of jobs he entered in the textbox will then appear in a listbox. I also have 5 textboxes that will be enabled according to how many jobs the user enter. In these textboxes, the users are required to enter the runtime value. I would like to get the average waiting time and the average turn around time without sorting the arrangements of the job numbers and the runtime. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . It doesn't fit within the scope of SO as well as it does code review's.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are several things that you can do:

- The calculation of `y` is the same in every case, so you don't have to repeat it.
- The last `ElseIf` will always be true, so just use an `Else`
- Using `Val(0)` will cause a lot of implicit conversions, it will actually end up being `CStr(Val(Cstr(0)))`, so just use `"0"`.

Code:

```
ElseIf Val(jobs_txt.Text) = 3 Then
  If (a < b And b < c) Then
    awt1_lbl.Text = "0"
    awt2_lbl.Text = a
    awt3_lbl.Text = a + b
  ElseIf (a < c And c < b) Then
    awt1_lbl.Text = "0"
    awt2_lbl.Text = a + b
    awt3_lbl.Text = a
  ElseIf (b < a And a < c) Then
    awt1_lbl.Text = a
    awt2_lbl.Text = "0"
    awt3_lbl.Text = a + b
  ElseIf (b < c And c < a) Then
    awt1_lbl.Text = a + b
    awt2_lbl.Text = "0"
    awt3_lbl.Text = a
  ElseIf (c < a And a < b) Then
    awt1_lbl.Text = a
    awt2_lbl.Text = a + b
    awt3_lbl.Text = "0"
  Else
    awt1_lbl.Text = a + b
    awt2_lbl.Text = a
    awt3_lbl.Text = "0"
  End If
  y = (Val(awt1_lbl.Text) + Val(awt2_lbl.Text) + Val(awt3_lbl.Text)) / 3
  awt_ans.Text = y
```

Actually, if the values doesn't have to be converted to strings and then back to numbers, you can simply calculate `y` like this:

```
y = (a * 2 + b) / 3
```

Comment: Is it a given that a,b,c will all be unique numbers? What if `a = b` or `a = c`?

Comment: @jonlester: Good point. I assumed that they were. I don't know if the code makes sense at all if they are not unique...

Comment: OP has confirmed they are.... i'll keep my nose out!

Answer (score 3):

First, it looks like you can move the last two lines

```
y = (Val(awt1_lbl.Text) + Val(awt2_lbl.Text) + Val(awt3_lbl.Text)) / 3
awt_ans.Text = y
```

outside of the `if-then-else`, because they do the same thing in all six cases.

Next, since it looks like your code assigns Val(0) to the item with the smallest key, `a+b` to the value in the middle, and `a` to the largest one, you can put `a`, `b`, and `c` in an array of keys, `awt1_lbl`, `awt2_lb`, and `awt3_lbl` into an array of values, and sort them, like this:

```
Dim keys() As String = { a, b, c }
Dim labels() As LabelType = { awt1_lbl, awt2_lb, awt3_lbl } // put real label type there
Array.Sort(keys, labels)
labels(0).Text = Val(0)
labels(1).Text = a+b
labels(2).Text = a
```

Comment: @downvoter Could you please explain your vote? This answer shrinks OP's code to mere eight lines, what could be wrong with this approach?

Comment: -1 because it would not compile with option strict or might result in a incorrect result(concattening string instead of adding numbers). Also this approach might be the shortest but it's not  reusable, maintanable or extendable. It might work today but not tomorrow when logic(or view) changes.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is not *code*, this is an *illustration of an approach*. It is up to the user to decide on his compile options, and what to do with the numbers. As far as maintainability or extensibility goes, give me a break: how is **eight** lines of code based on a *standard* .NET library less maintainable, less reusable, or otherwise inferior to a program with **forty** lines of utterly custom code? P.S. downvoting a competing answer on a subjective opinion is **always** an exercise in pettiness, no exceptions.

Comment: I agree with dasblinkenlight. Code which compiles is preferable, and maybe he should have pointed out that it's pseudo-code, but apart from that, it's a perfectly good answer. Not having a bunch of If/ElseIf statements make this approach way more maintainable, so I don't get Tim's point.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a class of it, then it's easier to read, reuse maintain and extend:

```
Dim awt = New AWT(a, b, c)
awt1_lbl.Text = awt.GetAWT1().ToString
awt2_lbl.Text = awt.GetAWT2().ToString
awt3_lbl.Text = awt.GetAWT3().ToString
awt_ans.Text  = awt.GetY().ToString
```

And here is a possible implementation, i've made it [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) so that it could easily be translated to C# and also is less error-prone.

```
Public Class AWT
    Public Property A As Int32
    Public Property B As Int32
    Public Property C As Int32

    Public Sub New(a As Int32, b As Int32, c As Int32)
        Me.A = a
        Me.B = b
        Me.C = c
    End Sub

    Public Function GetY() As Int32
        Return GetAWT1() + GetAWT2() + GetAWT3()
    End Function

    Public Function GetAWT1() As Int32
        If (A < B AndAlso B < C) OrElse (A < C AndAlso C < B) Then
            Return 0
        ElseIf (B < A AndAlso A < C) OrElse (C < A AndAlso A < B) Then
            Return A
        Else
            Return A + B
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function GetAWT2() As Int32
        If (A < B AndAlso B < C) OrElse (C < B AndAlso B < A) Then
            Return A
        ElseIf (A < C AndAlso C < B) OrElse (C < A AndAlso A < B) Then
            Return A + B
        Else 
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function GetAWT3() As Int32
        If (A < B AndAlso B < C) OrElse (B < A AndAlso A < C) Then
            Return A + B
        ElseIf (A < C AndAlso C < B) OrElse (B < C AndAlso C < A) Then
            Return A
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Using a class is a good idea, but I don't think all those If/ElseIf are really necessary. See answer from dasblinkenlight.

Comment: The conditions might change, apart from that i don't know the logic behind that. So without more informations i would prefer methods in a separate class that encapsulate complexity. Besides those are all integers and not strings, so dasblinkenlight's approach wouldn't even compile with option strict. OP doesn't want to concat strings but  to add numbers.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>In addition to other answers, this:</strike>

```
If (a < b And b < c) Then
```

should be the same as:

```
If (a < b < c) Then
```

Saves you a few characters!

Edit: MetaKnight is right, **this isn't valid syntax.**  Yet compiler doesn't complain and i can't figure out what it does.

Comment: Yes the program I am creating requires that a,b,c,d and e are all unique number. Thanks for suggesting the last part.

Comment: Well, the syntax works, but it doesn't do the same thing as the original code. It will first compare `a` and `b`, which results in a boolean value, then it will compare `c` to that boolean. If you have `Option Strict Off` it will allow the conversion that makes the comparison possible, but the result makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain.